# What is the meaning of "The transistors Q1,Q2 are identical" and of "Q1/Q2 = 10"

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog

What is the meaning of the given data

> Two transistors Q1,Q2 are identical

Does it mean that they have the same working point (I_C,V_CE), or maybe that only one of these parameters is identical? Or maybe it means that the \beta is also identical? I encounter this data from time to time but I can't find anywher the definition.. i.e.

> "We say that two transistors Q1 and Q2 are identical if: 1)...,2)... etc.."

I have the same problem with the data of sizes relation i.e. I can't find the definition for:

> "We say that two transistors satisfy Q1/Q2 = 10 if: 1)...,2)... etc.."

I would be very helpful for me if anyone would know these definitions or where to find them..

Thanks!

Comment: Q1 and Q2 being identical means that every physical characteristic of them is identical. It's the intuitive use of the word identical, not some special technical term.

Comment: How do you define identical?  What is the most important characteristic of a transistor?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, this is exactly my question, what is the *definition* of this terms..

Comment: From a real world perspective, two whatevers can NOT be identical (or matched), there is some slight differences.  But from a theoretical perspective, two whatevers can be identical, where as Hearth says every physical characteristic is the same or identical.

Comment: Be aware of the thermal matching in using transistors. If one device has 1 volt and 1ma, and its twin has 20 volts and 1mA, the emitter-bases are not at the same temperatures. Assuming these are identical transistors (bipolars), each degree C of mismatch causes about 2.2 millivolts mismatch in Vbe and about 5% current mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

> Two transistors Q1,Q2 are identical

Unfortunately you do not describe in which context this statement is made.

I have seen such statements before in the context of **analog IC design**. On a chip we can make transistors that are "identical" in the sense that they have very similar transistor parameters like \$\beta\$ and what \$V_{BE}\$ you get under certain circumstances.

This has **nothing** to do with "external parameters" like \$V_{CE}\$ because these are mostly defined by the circuit in which a transistor is used.

On an IC transistors can be identical as they're all made **at the same time**.

Discrete transistors can be identical but you'll have to do your best to find a pair that  is identical enough. You might never find a pair like that.

The most basic application of "identical" transistors is a current mirror:

[image]

Where TR1 converts I1 into a (\$V_{BE}\$) voltage which is then applied to an identical transistor TR2 which then makes a copy of I1 flow, which is I2.

For identical transistors I1 = I2 (ignoring some 2nd order effects).

Comment: The statement should always be read as "these two transistors are **identical enough for our immediate purposes**".  Even on an IC they aren't going to be *exactly* identical -- just a lot closer to each other than two randomly chosen discrete transistors with the same part number.

Comment: Diodes Inc makes transistor pairs on the same die that for many purposes are *identical enough*. I recently did a cascode mirror with them and it worked a treat.

Comment: I see thanks this helps. What about "Q1/Q2 = 10" or "Q1 is ten times bigger then Q2", do you know what does this data, when given, means?

Comment: @user135172 Q1/Q2 = 10 means that Q1 is 10x larger than Q2. For a BJT: the emitter area will be 10x larger, for MOSFETs: the width will be 10x larger. It is also possible to just connect 10 transistors in parallel.